# How can I find out the number of cases that satisfy a condition before and after another column

Tags: r

```
df <- data.frame(
  ID = 1:3,
  SMOKE_AUT10 = c(0, 0, 0),
  SMOKE_SPR10 = c(0, 0, 0),
  SMOKE_SUM10 = c(0, 1, 1),
  SMOKE_AUT11 = c(0, 0, 0),
  HD_AUT10 = c(0, 0, 0),
  HD_SPR10 = c(1, 1, 0),
  HD_SUM10 = c(1, 1, 0),
  HD_AUT11 = c(1, 0, 1)
)
```

Imagine this df in R. AUT,SPR and SUM refer to seasons where a census occurs. SMOKE means do they smoke or not (coded as 1 or 0) and HD is whether they have been identified as having heart disease (coded as 1 or 0). I am trying to figure out:

1. how many individuals had a HD flag before they started smoking
2. how many individuals went on/developed a HD flag after they started smoking.

I am not sure how to approach the problem. I thought about pivoting the data and creating some IF statements but there's lots of censuses (I only put 4 for convenience).

Comment: The number in *SMOKE_AUT11* is the year?

Comment: @AndreWildberg No, sorry. SMOKE_AUT11 is just whether they smoked on that census day. The AUT,SPR,SUM[year_number] just refers to the term of the census and the year it took place in.

Comment: So if an individual never smoked but develops HD, does it fall into category 1.)?

Comment: How is it that person 1 had HD in summer 2010 (June 2010) but no disease in Autumn 2010(Sept 2010) then had disease in Autumn 2011(September 2011)?

Comment: @AndreWildberg no. That's its own category I guess. I figured I could calculate that with a much simpler if statement. It's the other two categories, I can't figure out.

Comment: @Onyambu That's a really good point. It was just an example. Let's say instead, HD is just a flag for "risk of Heart Disease" (maybe it was a poor measure). Instead of Smoking and HD, maybe you could think of other scenarios - e.g. swap out "Smoke" for "In_Prison" and "HD" for "Homeless". so how many who were in prison had previously been homeless and how many went on to become homeless. I hope that makes sense. The specific variables do not matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we only consider when the first incident occurred and leave out non-smoker.

Since the columns are not ordered we have to sort them first (per year and per season).

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

dff <- df %>% pivot_longer(-ID)

dff <- dff %>% arrange(ID, str_extract(name, "\\d+$")) # year order

dff <- do.call(rbind, lapply(c("SPR", "SUM", "AUT"), \(x) 
  dff[grep(x, dff$name),])) %>% arrange(ID) # season order

dff %>% 
  group_by(ID, grp = sub("_.*", "", name)) %>% 
  summarize(mm = min(if_else(value == 1, row_number(), Inf)), 
            mm = if_else(is.infinite(mm), NA, mm)) %>% 
  summarize(HD_after_SMOKE = mm[grp == "SMOKE"] < mm[grp == "HD"], 
            HD_before_SMOKE = mm[grp == "SMOKE"] > mm[grp == "HD"]) %>%
  summarize(across(starts_with("HD"), ~ sum(.x, na.rm=T)))
# A tibble: 1 × 2
  HD_after_SMOKE HD_before_SMOKE
           <int>           <int>
1              1               1
```

Comment: Thank you!! This is so helpful. I guess I could just write of those who have smoked, X% developed HD after and X had it before. This was just what I was after. I presume this captures "ever" develop or is it just the subsequent census/season.

I think I am too stupid to understand @Onyambu  solution.

Comment: @allen.joseph No worries, he has a point though. I just saw that the columns are not ordered "spring", "summer", "autumn". We have to oder them first. See edit!

Comment: Just to confirm, that's to make sure the HD and SMOKE are in order by season (e.g. SMOKE_SPR10 followed by HD_SPR10) or did you mean just the seasons (e.g. it could be SMOKE_SPR10 followed by SMOKE_SUM10, SMOKE_AUT10 etc.)

Comment: @allen.joseph I tested the code with completely shuffled column order. Should work fine with any given season or year. Btw, if you need an additional season just add it to the „lapply“ line in the right position.

Answer (score 0):

```
nms <- c(SPR =  "March 1 ", SUM = "June 1 ",
                AUT = "September 1 ", WIN = "December 1 ")

first_one <- function(x) min(which(x > 0)[1], Inf, na.rm = TRUE)

df1 <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(-ID, names_to = c('.value', 'grp'), names_sep = '_')%>%
  mutate(date_begin = mdy(str_replace_all(grp, nms))) %>%
  arrange(ID, date_begin) %>%
  summarise(hd_before = first_one(HD) < first_one(SMOKE),
            hd_after = first_one(HD) > first_one(SMOKE), .by = ID)
df1

     ID hd_before hd_after
  <int> <lgl>     <lgl>   
1     1 TRUE      FALSE   
2     2 TRUE      FALSE   
3     3 FALSE     TRUE
```

From the above you could compute the number by summing the columns:

```
colSums(df1[-1])
hd_before  hd_after 
        2         1
```